# calling prop from child component in a function dosen't work

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to pass a prop from child to parent component(exactly, call a function in parent when some work done in child). but it dosen't work such that i want!

this is some codes of child compomnent:

```
  handle = () =>
    {
      return this.props.DoLoggin;
    }
  render(){
    return(
    <Button  onPress={this.handle}><Text>Click</Text></Button>
    );
  }
```

and parent :

```
handler = ()=> {
console.log('Logged In :)');
}
render(){
return (
<Login DoLoggin={this.handler}/>
);
}
```

Note : when i use the call prop in a method like onPress in Child component , it works! :

```
render(){
return(
<Button onPress={this.props.DoLoggin}><Text>Click</Text></Button>
);
}
```

But that is not what i want! i want call prop, in a function to do some work automatically!

Comment: Can you please give an example that does not work for you or what do you expect to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it worked directly is because you were not calling the function itself. It is just a reference to the function that will be called when user presses the Button. Since you are using your custom handler, you have to call the function in the `return` statement

You have to call the prop function inside your `handle` function.

```
  handle = () =>
    {
      return this.props.DoLoggin();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it:

```
handle = () =>
{
  return this.props.DoLoggin(); //not this.props.DoLoggin;
}
```